# Using Cohen's f squared to calculate effect size between rank-based correlation coefficients

Tags: effect-size

Is it reasonable to use a Cohen's f squared to calculate an effect size between two Spearman's correlation coefficients that are squared and equivalent to R squared?

The idea is that this comparison is approximately equivalent to a sequential multiple regression statistical situation where the square of the Spearman's correlation coefficient can be treated as R squared.

Is it also reasonable to use a Cohen's f squared in a similar manner to calculate an effect size between to Kendall tau correlation coefficients that are squared?

My final statistical situation is to estimate a p-value for the difference between median Kendall tau correlation coefficients for two experimental groups. More specifically, it is comparing the median Kendall tau correlation between groups as compared to the median Kendall tau correlation coefficient within either group.  If the Cohen's f squared can serve as the effect size, then this should be straight-forward.  I expect the estimated p-value to be an upper bound of the p-value since the median correlation for the set of biological sample to biological sample correlations is being used.

Also, if anyone has any references for this type of approach that would be greatly appreciated.